# Saving an indoor Meyer lemon tree with a couple leaves left

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, citrus, lemons, dead-branch

I’ve had this Meyer lemon tree since January. It was doing well, blossoming, etc. but in the past 2 months it’s slowly lost most of its leaves. I used to water it once a week and mist the leaves daily for humidity. It gets 12 hours of light via a plant light. I repotted it into a bigger pot around March and it seemed fine after that. The potting soil is Miracle Gro Cactus Palm and Citrus Fast Draining Potting Soil.

Initially some of the leaves had some mottling so I suspected some sort of fungus and I decreased the watering (at one point waiting 3 weeks in between) but it hasn’t made much of a difference. I’ve tried watering with diluted hydrogen peroxide to kill any larvae. I have a sticky trap in the pot that looks like it caught several  (fungus?) gnats, but I haven’t noticed new ones in the past couple weeks. I have also tried spraying a fungicide (Fung-onil) and a Neem oil solution. I read that good circulation can help, but I live in a first floor apartment and can’t really keep my window open while I’m not home. Meanwhile my other plant (a jasmine) has been thriving right next to this struggling lemon tree.

I have read some of the other posts on this topic but would appreciate specific advice. The bottom of both trunks still has some green and I really hope I can save my tree.

Thanks so much!

[image: Lemon tree]

Comment: Not an expert on lemon trees but those dark spots on the trunk can't be a good sign. Are you certain the light you ave is enough for the tree? The tree need more sun during the growing season, if the root is doing fine(not over watered) then I would think it's because the lack of light. again, I don't know if your light is strong enough or not

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have different two plant lights for the tree (5 bulbs total) but I guess it could be possible this still isn’t enough light. I wonder if the black spots on the trunk might be fungal. there a way to check the status of the roots?

Comment: Well the only way to check the roots is to look at the roots, whatever way you want to use for that is up to you. Grow light varies so much that it is hard to say what is enough. Some plant/trees require more some less, it's hard to say. I believe you have to find out how many lumens the lights are outputting and how much the tree needs, it's a whole different topic that I am not familiar with. You could go in a store and ask but nothing beats the sun, the sun is also free

Comment: Good question; if could include an overall illustration & closer illustration of the top & leaves, overall height, current watering amount & frequency, current nutrient amount & frequency, size of container, and if some coarse gravel in the bottom and a hole in the bottom for good aereation & drainage, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!